# jQuery UI's autocomplete doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I always have problems with jQuery UI, and so I do now. I want to use it's autocomplete feature, so I wrote a little results page which returns JSON response like this:

```
[ { "value": "2", "label": "Baldur's Gate" }, { "value": "3", "label": "Baldur's Gate 2" }, ];
```

And my JS is:

```
function extractLast(term) {
    //return split( term ).pop();
    var t = term.replace(' ', '%20');
    return t;
}

$('nav#mainMenu input').autocomplete({
    minLength:3,
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON('/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/search/g/' + extractLast(request['term']), response);
    }
});
```

As you see, it's pretty basic and I think I forgot about something quite obvious, but yet I can't see what could that be. Any ideas?

Comment: seems to be fine here http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uTTGZ/ with out ajax, can you check whether the ajax request is success and data is proper

Comment: Data is fine, and in my inspector I can see the `get` is being made. Only the DOM isn't modified properly.

Comment: Can you change `$.getJSON('/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/search/g/' + extractLast(request['term']), response);` to `$.getJSON('/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/search/g/' + extractLast(request['term']), function(data){console.log(data);response(data)})`;

Comment: Tried that, it isn't showing up in console.

Comment: that means the ajax request is failing

Comment: But console show's that GET is being made and it returns good results. What should I do?

Comment: Try this, it should give an error in the console `$.ajax({
 url: '/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/search/g/' + extractLast(request['term']),
 dataType: 'json' 
}).done(function(data){
 console.log(data);
 response(data);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
 console.log(jqXHR);
 console.log(textStatus);
 console.log(errorThrown);
});`

Comment: It gives parseerror and "Syntax error: Unexpected token"

Comment: that means your response is not proper json. Can you share the response text

Comment: My repponse is posted in my question.

Comment: is it coming with `;` at the end, if yes remove it

Comment: updated my answer, there were 2 more problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally made it ;)

The problem was the data returned to jQuery. I succeeded by using `json_encode` with my array. Here's the code:

```
$results = $search->getResult();
$tab = array();

foreach($results as $result) {
    $tab[] = array('label' => $result->getName(), 'value' => $result->getName(), 'id' => $result->getID());
}

try {
    return new Response(json_encode($tab));

} catch (\Doctrine\Orm\NoResultException $e) {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there are multiple problems with the returned value. It should be

```
[ { "value": "2", "label": "Baldur\'s Gate" }, { "value": "3", "label": "Baldur\'s Gate 2" } ]
```

1. The `'` should be escaped with `\'`
2. There is a `,` after the second object, it is invalid
3. The `;` at the end of the response should be removed.

`jQuery.ajax` uses [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) to parse the `responseText`. It is specified via the `"text json": jQuery.parseJSON` converter configuration in [jQuery.js](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.js) file.

If you pass your response to this method it fails

```
jQuery.parseJSON('[ { "value": "2", "label": "Baldur's Gate" }, { "value": "3", "label": "Baldur's Gate 2" }, ];')
```

Comment: So I just pasted your return value and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try `jQuery.parseJSON('[ { "value": "2", "label": "Baldur\'s Gate" }, { "value": "3", "label": "Baldur\'s Gate 2" } ]')` in your console

Answer (score 0):

It may also be the , at the end of the [ ] of your autocomplete-list. IE doesn't like that.